# No error message or log with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

All requests to my Laravel site are getting 500 errors and being rendered with `app/views/web/errors/500.blade.php` (as opposed to the standard Laravel error details page). That public error page obviously doesn't provide any error details and nothing is being written to my apache log. If I screw with `app.php` (e.g. load a bogus package), I get the normal Laravel error page with stack trace, server state, etc.

How do I figure out what is causing this 500 error?

- I have `'debug' => true` in `app/config/app.php`.
- Permissions are 777 for everything.

Comment: Have you set 777 permissions to your storage/logs/ folder? If yes, is there anything logged there?

Comment: Of course! I forgot. There is better error details in the laravel log. If you want to put that as an answer, I will mark it as the answer. Otherwise, Im going to delete this out of embarrassment.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.This is a very common mistake and could probably be useful for people who would have same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give 777 permissions to your `storage/logs/` folder. Laravel writes all the logs to the files in this folder.

Hope this helps